# AngularJS populate ng-options with object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I go about populating a select if I was using ng-options?

So I have something like,

```
<select ng-model="option.model"
ng-options="option as (option.firstVal + ' ' + option.secondVal) 
  for option in options>
<option value="">default</option>
```

The value in each option is an entire object and the ng-option is going through a collection of objects.

I need the value to be the entire object to be the value so I can't use ng-repeat. When I try to assign the model to the object itself,

```
$scope.option.model = option; //option is made elsewhere
```

It doesn't work. It'll populate the field with the default option.

[Edit 1]
In this example, the dropdown should be selected to John Rambo, but instead it goes to the default

jsfiddle.net/brzxn8yt/1

Comment: this plunkr shows the best way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/derkoe/KN9xx/presentation/, please let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Not exactly, what I'm looking for is how to populate the batch with a given option object. So the default option is the one that has the value of the option object.

Comment: what you have said is very confusing, could you make a jsfiddle with the sample data to look into, maybe highlight the issue in comments inside the JSFiddle?

Comment: Forking your fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/brzxn8yt/1/ .
In theory, the dropdown should be selected to John Rambo, but instead it goes to the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to use the track by property of ng-options. in the below example I track the object by the ID property.

**Note:** Please use a unique property in the object (E.g: id would be perfect since there are no duplicates, but actor property has duplicates and will throw and error).

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.people = [
        { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo', actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa', actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble', actor: 'Arnold' },
        { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards', actor: 'Arnold' }
    ];
    
    $scope.selectedPerson = { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo', actor: 'Silvester' }; // a person object
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select 
            ng-options="item as item.first + ' ' + item.last for item in people track by item.id"
            ng-model="selectedPerson">
              <option value="">Default</option>
            </select>
        {{ selectedPerson }}
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Reference:**

[ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)